# i need to print currently no products in my laravel page using else condtion

Tags: laravel

i need to print currently no products in my laravel page using else condtion

```
@foreach ($data['products'] as $list)
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4 tt-col-item">
  <div class="tt-product thumbprod-center">
   <div class="tt-description">
    <div class="tt-row">
    </div>
    <h2 class="tt-title">
      <a href="{{url('/Shop/'.$data['webname'].'/products/'.$list['id'].'/details')}}">{{
   $list['name'] }}
      </a>
    </h2>                                   
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>     
@endforeach
```

Comment: what have you tried ? you have an extra `</div>` in your code

Comment: if I put else condition its showing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I think I know what you want to accomplish. Before your foreach you need to check the products count. If products are found, then loop them, if not, display a message. Try this:

```
@if(count($data['products']))
   
@foreach ($data['products'] as $list)
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 tt-col-item">
        <div class="tt-product thumbprod-center">
            <div class="tt-description">
                <div class="tt-row">
                                                
                </div>
                <h2 class="tt-title"><a href="{{url('/Shop/'.$data['webname'].'/products/'.$list['id'].'/details')}}">{{
   $list['name'] }}</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                                      
@endforeach

@else
   <p>Currently no products.</p>
@endif
```

Comment: blade has a directive(s) for this `forelse/empty`, btw

Comment: I'm aware of that, but wanted to provide the simplest solution, so the OP could understand the flow of the execution.

Comment: i love how you still copied the extra `</div>`